# On Retrofit2, If json from server is like this, How can i set json class?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

If i get json form as like follows, How should i set Postitem class?

```
 {
    "author": "1122",
    "text": "ggg",
    "image": "https://www.landscape.com/irenepretty",
    "point": {
      "longitude": "-4.921875",
      "latitude": "13.974609375"
    }
 }
```

I wrote

```
public class Postitem implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @Expose
    private String image;
}
```

But i don't know how to make it about "point"

Could you teach me?

Comment: you may use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Are you using gson?

Comment: Yes, i'm using json, Thank you for advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to make another class as Point like this:

```
public class Point{
    @Expose
    private double latitude;
    @Expose
    private double longitude;
}
```

and have your PostItem like this:

```
public class Postitem implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @Expose
    private Point point;
}
```

Another way is just store them as jsonobject like this:

If you are using Gson you can use it like this:

```
public class Postitem implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @Expose
    private JSONObject point;
}
```

Then you need a deserializer which is like this:

```
public class JsonObjectDeserializer<J> implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer<JSONObject> {
    @Override
    public JSONObject deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json.isJsonObject()) {
            String value = json.getAsJsonObject().toString();
            try {
                return new JSONObject(value);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (json.isJsonArray()) {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
            try {
                object.put("array", new JSONArray(json.getAsJsonArray().toString()));
                return object;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then you need to register the deserializer with retrofit like this:

```
Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory
                        .create(
                                new GsonBuilder()
                                        .registerTypeAdapter(
                                                JSONObject.class,
                                                new JsonObjectDeserializer()
                                        )
                                        .create()));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can first make pojo class : like this

```
            @JsonProperty("author")
           private String author;
           @JsonProperty("text")
            private String text;
          @JsonProperty("image")
         private String image;
         @JsonProperty("point")
        private Point point;
```

Now Point is a class which will have lat and long as variables

```
    public class Point {

    @JsonProperty("longitude")
    private String longitude;
     @JsonProperty("latitude")
    private String latitude;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Postitem implements Serializable {
    @Expose
    private String author;
    @Expose
    private String text;
    @Expose
    private String image;
    @Expose
    private Point point;

    public class Point implements Serializable {
        @Expose
        private double longitude;
        @Expose
        private double latitude;
    }  
}
```